# Convert 3gpp to mp3 using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3, 3gp

I am trying to convert a recorded file on an Android device using Phonegap from .3gpp to .mp3 using ffmpeg libary.

When I execute the code on the command line for conversion,

[image]

I get following errors:

[image]

Can any one please help me with this as I am novice in media conversion.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code and commands. Please paste them here so they're searchable and easier to read.

Comment: I tried hard to add the script under the code tag but it did not worked. Hence, I had to attach the screenshots. In future, I will make that note. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your picture, that version is over 4 years old and is unsupported.

I strongly suggest upgrading which should resolve this issue. You can download a recent version from [Zeranoe FFmpeg Windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: This is really helpful. It worked...!!! Thank you very much Steven